# Wordpress adding thumbnails to category

Tags: wordpress

How to take on a problem in WordPress admin editing. 
I'd like to edit an `edit-category` admin panel to add a featured image to it (just like in posts), but I'm a bit indecisive since a lot of people use a custom field with static path to a photo, but I'm wondering is there a way to do it better(enable some wp hook and such).

Can someone point me in the right direction?

---

Thanks for the plugin it seems good, but i have one additional problem. It seems i have a lack of knowledge on how to query an object [category] so i can apply filters, hope im making some sense. This is done on my home.php. all dumps are null

```
<?php get_header(); 
$listcat = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
foreach($listcat as $x){
    $img = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '');
    var_dump($img);
}           
 get_footer(); ?>
```

The same code works with no problems if i stick it in category.php. Any ideas? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've used several times the plugin "Taxonomy Images". it works with multi-language wp installs too.

link with instruction: http://wordpress.mfields.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/

Comment: Thanks for the plugin it seems good, but i have one additional problem. It seems i have a lack of knowledge on how to query an object [category] so i can apply filters, hope im making some sense. This is done on my home.php. all dumps are null 

    <?php get_header(); 
    $listcat = get_categories('hide_empty=0');
    foreach($listcat as $x){
     $img = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-queried-term-image', '');
     var_dump($img);
    }   
     get_footer(); ?>
The same code works with no problems if i stick it in category.php. Any ideas? :)

Comment: if you var_dump ($x) does your query return the categories?